# Função retornando undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js

[image: Função retornando undefined]

Função retornando undefined, não sei o que fazer

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aproveite um pouco do teu tempo para ler para ler sobre [Como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas).

O que você precisa é retornar uma [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) do método `getUserById`, exemplo em base ao código que você postou:

```
function getUserById(id){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sql.connect((err) => {
      if(err)
        return reject(err);
        
      sql.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id], (error result, fields) => {
        if(error)
          return reject(error);
          
        return resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Note as diferenças entre o código acima e o que você escreveu:

- getUserById recebe como parâmetro somente o id e retorna uma promise que pode ser resolvida ou rejeitada em caso de erros (é importante pensar aos possíveis erros)
- NUNCA, mas NUNCA mesmo insira o valor de uma variável diretamente no corpo da query, use o escape (?) e passe o valor das variáveis como um array no segundo parâmetro da função.
- O terceiro parâmetro do método `query` é uma função que será chamada quando a sua query retornar algum resultado.

Mas olhe o quão feio é esse código acima, cada vez que você faz uma query você abre um conexão com o DB que a propósito nunca foi fechada, o código cheio de `callbacks`, visto que não foi especificado na pergunta qual módulo você está usando, eu recomendo o uso do [MySql Promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql), que irá facilitar muito o uso das promises em suas queries, mesmo exemplo acima porém escrito melhor:

```
const db = require('mysql-promise')();

// Inicializa a conexão com o database
db.isConfigured() || db.configure(DB_CONFIGURATIONS_HERE);

const getUserById = (id) => db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id]);
```

Ou como eu faço nos meus projetos, crio um módulo que se ocupa somente de realizar a conexão com o Database e as queries de maneira que o mesmo possa ser usado em diferentes partes da aplicação, exemplo:

```
const db = require('mysql-promise')();

// Inicializa a conexão com o database
db.isConfigured() || db.configure(DB_CONFIGURATIONS_HERE);

module.exports = {
  shutdownPool: () => db.end(),
  
  getUserById = (id) => db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id]),
}
```

E para chamar qualquer um dos métodos acima basta fazer:

```
getUserById(1)
.then((resultado) => { ... tudo funcionou e você tem uma resposta })
.catch((error) => {... algo deu errado})
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
try{
   const resultado = await getUserById(1);
   // Tudo ok, faça algo com o resultado

}catch(error){
   // Algo deu errado
}
```

Comment: brabíssimo, thx